# When is an address saved to the customer?

Tags: orders, customer, billing-address

When is an address saved in the customer? I mean, is it in the checkout process when saveBilling is called? Or is in the conversion from quote to order when saveOrder is called?

In this question, save means the address can be reused by the customer in another purchase without having to type the address again.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to know where the address is being saved and related to a customer.

Comment: Take a look at `submitOrder()` in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php`

Comment: Why do you think there is where the relation between customer and address is being made?

Comment: Upvote from me for goof questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage

Magento **create object** of   **customer  form address**

```
Mage::getModel('customer/form');
        $addressForm->setFormCode('customer_address_edit')
->setEntityType('customer_address');
```

then

on function `_prepareNewCustomerQuote` and _`prepareCustomerQuote`  magento copy `sales_quote_address fields object`  to `customer address object using`   from field copy `Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset()` function  and `Mage_Customer_Address function  -addAddress`which `copy  fields between customer_address and order quote object` and here also **set default shipping and billing address** which **default selecting on next time in checkout**

Comment: Nice answer, Very helpful :-)